# Time complexity of nested while loop inside nested for loop

Tags: time-complexity

I am having a little bit of difficulty analyzing the time complexity of this algorithm:

```
for i = 1 to n do
   for j = 1 to n do
      k = j
      while k <= n do
        k = k*3
      end while
   end for
end for
```

I know that the outer `for` loop will run `n` times, and the inner `for` loop will run `n^2` times. However, for the `while` loop, I've narrowed the cost down to `n^2 + (some factor)*n`, but I don't know where to go from here. I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: The `while` loop itself is nowhere near `O(n^2)`. Its complexity depends on the value of `j` too, which (hint) has a possibly surprising effect on the total complexity.

Comment: You're right. The `while` loop speeds up the inner `for` loop because of the `k = j` assignment in each iteration. However, I'm still not sure about the total complexity. I get that it is still `O(n^2)` due to the two `for` loops (even though the latter gets reduced faster for each iteration), but I'm not sure how the `while` loop affects the runtime big `O` notation wise.

Comment: Are you familiar with this form of loop, where the iteration variable is multiplied by a constant every time?

Comment: Kind of. So far I've only worked with rather simple examples I feel.

Comment: The complexity of a loop such as this is *logarithmic*, **however** (hint) the total complexity *does not* include a logarithm term.

Comment: I see that I still have to work on recognizing logarithmic loops. Is that always the case for loops where a constant is multiplied with the iteration variable in each iteration?

As for the total complexity, I think it is `O(n^2 + log(n)) => O(n^2)`

Comment: For the most part, yes (except if the constant is negative - will need to be cautious in that situation). I'm puzzled as to how you deduced that the logarithmic term is *added*?

Comment: My bad. It was supposed to be `O((n^2)*log(n)) => O(n^2)`. However, I'm still unsure about why the logarithmic term is not included in the total complexity. Wouldn't it matter for large inputs?

Comment: `O((n^2)*log(n))` does *not* round down to `O(n^2)` since the `log n` is multiplied. The logarithmic term is actually not present *at all*. (And a small nit-pick, O-notation already *is* for describing large inputs.) I'll post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can immediately factor out the outer for-loop, since none of the inner logic depends on its iteration variable `i`.

Now let's look at the while loop. You have correctly deduced that it is logarithmic - but what variables does it depend on? After the `m`-th execution of this loop, the value of `k` is:

[image]

The loop breaks when this is greater than `n`, so the number of times `max(m)` it executes is:

[image]

The total complexity, equal to `n` times the combined complexity of the inner for-loop and this while-loop is therefore the following summation:

[image]

What do we do about the rounding brackets? If you round a number up to the nearest integer, the result always differs from the original number by *less than 1*. Therefore the difference can just be written as a constant `O(1)`:

[image]

Where in:

- (1), (2), (4) we used three of the logarithm rules,
- (3) we used the definition of the *factorial* `n! = n(n-1)(n-2)...1`,
- **(4)** we used [*Stirling's approximation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

> Thus the total time complexity is:
>
> [image]
>
> And as I mentioned in the comments, *there is no logarithmic term or factor*.

---

**EDIT** numerical tests to confirm this result. JavaScript code:

```
function T(n) {
   var m = 0;
   for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      for (var j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
         var k = j;
         while (k <= n) {
            k *= 3;
            m++;
         }
      }
   }
   return m;
}
```

Test results:

```
n       T(n)
-----------------
1000    1498000
1500    3370500
2000    5992000
2500    9365000
3000    13494000
3500    18357500
4000    23984000
4500    30361500
5000    37475000
5500    45347500
6000    53976000
6500    63336000
7000    73472000
7500    84345000
8000    95952000
8500    108324000
9000    121482000
9500    135337000
10000   149960000
```

Plot of `T(n)` against `n^2`:

[image]

A very tidy straight line, which proves that `T(n)` is directly proportional to `n^2` for large inputs.